# Error while Creating New Web Application

Tags: 2010, central-administration, sql-server

**Environment :** SharePoint 2010.

**Description:**  I am trying to create new web-application through Central Admin. Once I click on '`New`' I am getting below error.

[image: Login failed for user 'sa'.] 
**Steps Performed till now:**

- Verified below based on this [article](https://www.eukhost.com/forums/f15/login-failed-user-sa-microsoft-sql-server-error-18456-a-12544/)

  1. Login to the MSSQL Server Management Studio with Windows Authentication.
  2. In SQL Server Management Studio Object Explorer, right-click the server, and then click Properties.
  3. Under the Server Properties, select a page of "Security".
  4. Select the Server authentication as "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode" and click Ok.
- In event viewer I got found below error:

> SQL database login for 'master' on instance 'devsp01' failed.
>   Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.
>
> Login failed for user 'sa'.

In SQL Server I can see '`sa`' account under Security -> Logins

[image]

What could be possible reason?
What all things I need to verify?

**Edit:** After digging more I found below error message in event viewer.

> Login failed for user ‘sa’. Reason: Password did not match that for
>   the login provided. [CLIENT: ]

But I wonder, there is no change in password.

Comment: Check if you can login in SQL server using 'sa' user or not?

Comment: I am able to login using sa

Comment: Check that if 'sa' is mapped for 'master'  in User mapping in SQL Studio?

Comment: It is mapped to master and Config db for SP also

Comment: are you using the SA account in SharePoint? using sql authentication to connect SQL?

Comment: Also get the ULS logs for the correlation id and share here